# SQL select without duplicates Joined to another table by ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates, distinct

I have 2 tables that I would like join where the contactid is unique and has the highest allowance.

EMPLOYEE

| Employee ID | contactid | employerid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 555444333 | 25435566 |
| 2 | 555444333 | 84235621 |
| 3 | 234232144 | 57353457 |

EMPLOYEEDETAILS

| Employee ID | Annual Allowance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | £10000 |
| 2 | £1000 |
| 3 | £2000 |

I would like to achieve **below** where I want to show the EmployeeID with the highest allowance for the **unique contactid.**

| EmployeeID | contactid | Annual Allowance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 555444333 | £10000 |
| 3 | 234232144 | £2000 |

I have tried the SQL code below but it's not giving me the unique contactid with the highest allowance.

```
SELECT  EMPLOYEE.employeeid, EMPLOYEE.contactid, MAX(EMPLOYEEDETAILS.annualallowance)
from
cxm_employee EMPLOYEE
JOIN
cxm_employeedetails EMPLOYEEDETAILS ON EMPLOYEE.employeeid = EMPLOYEEDETAILS.employeeid
group by EMPLOYEE.employeeid,EMPLOYEE.employeecontactid
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to show the EmployeeID with the highest allowance for the unique contactid.

Your code does not work because it only brings the details of the current employee, letting along other employees that have the same `contactid`.

I think it is easier to do with window functions:

```sql
select *
from (
    select e.*, d.annualallowance,
        rank() over(partition by e.contactid order by d.annualallowance desc) rn
    from employee e
    inner join employeedetails d on d.employeeid = e.employeeid
) t
where rn = 1
```

`rank()` ranks employees having the same contact by descending annual allowance ; we can then use this information for filtering.

---

In pre-8.0 versions of MySQL, where window functions are not supported, an alternative uses a correlated subquery to retrieve the top allowance per contact; we can then use this information to filter the dataset :

```sql
select e.*, d.annualallowance
from employee e
inner join employeedetails d on d.employeeid = e.employeeid
where d.annualallowance = (
    select max(d1.annualallowance)
    from employee e1
    inner join employeedetails d1 on d1.employeeid = e1.employeeid
    where e1.contactid = e.contactid
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/whvoaFXD)**

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately, window functions is not supported for my work. Is there another way to achieve this without window functions?

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, the result was a bit strange.
Ended up with results with duplicate contactid with same allowance:

Comment: @user3233822: I see that I misread your question, and that my query was not generating the result you want. I updated my answer (both versions with and without window functions), and added a DB Fiddle for testing.

Comment: @user3233822 Yikes. IMO pre-8.0 MySQL doesn't even really qualify as a modern database. It's missing _so much_ that pretty much every other database has had since 2012: window functions, CTEs, proper NULL handling, lateral joins, I could go on and on. It's probably worth pushing for an upgrade.